# Passing a numpy array of arrays as an asterisk into a function changes the value of the first item in the array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a function that return a numpy ndarray and the values it returns looks right:

[image]

Two arrays with the values, `2.5` and `2.`. I need to pass this variable into a function, but if I do without an asterisk, it gives me this error:

> function takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

So I'm assuming it's parsing the value and assumes the two arrays should be two parameters even though the function accepts one.

The function that takes the array of arrays looks like this:

```
def validate_arrays(*arrays):
```

And this is what the arrays variable looks like when it's passed into the function:

[image]

The first value gets change to a class reference or something. I have a feeling that using the asterisk isn't right here. But it's what I found when looking this stuff up. And I'm very new to Python, so I don't know how you'd normally handle this situation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Note, it isn't clear from your screenshots (**don't post screen shots**) but that looks like a list holding two single-element arrays, not a list. In any case, objects aren't copied when they are passed to a function, if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the function is in a class and the class assumed the first value would be `self`. So changing the definition to:

```
def validate_arrays(self, arrays):
```

fixed it.